# android - Drag and drop in Listview

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am new to drag and drop functionality.Please provide the easy tutorials.I saw some where drag and drop functionality starts from 3.0 and above. is any possibility to use in the below versions? I want to use drag and drop functionality in List view. please can anybody help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the drag and drop feature with the support package.

All details are right here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

and here : http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Comment: I don't see any mention of drag and drop framework in the compatibility library, or on the page linked.

Comment: Surely there is a specific library for dragging and dropping ListView items. It is boasted about in the Material Design Guidelines. https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html#